# pyinstaller changes value of file path

Tags: python-3.x, path, pyinstaller

I am running the following code:

```
DIRECTORY_PATH = os.getcwd()
print(DIRECTORY_PATH)
print(__file__)
print(os.path.abspath(__file__))
input("Press enter to continue ...")
```

But I get different results when I run after I use pyinstaller versus running just the python script. Is there a way to get the directory that the exe is in?

[Running pyinstaller --onefile exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyVL6.png) (notice the blue powershell behind the black python shell that contains the command used to run the exe)

[Running python script with python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zFH9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found around this is to make a batch file to run the program from the same directory.

```
cd %~dp0
start program.exe
```

That way you get the directory path to the starting file even though its technically because its coming from the batch file.